# Is it possible to call a particular function in PHP using GET data?

Tags: php

I have a file **functions.php** which has multiple functions like:

```
function do_this(){
}

function do_that(){
}
```

Now, I am thinking doing something weird like calling that function from URL:

> functions.php?**func**=*do_that*

Now, I added this lines of code to **functions.php**

```
if(isset($_GET["func"])){
    $func = $_GET["func"];
    //How to call that function with name "$func"

}
```

Any great brains out there? Let me know. If that's not possible, then also lemme know. Coz I have to think of a new approach in my work.

Comment: I will let you know it is possible because  I do it. :) Enjoy!

Comment: That's called a [_variable function_](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) in PHP. USE EXTREME CAUTION! Only execute functions which are in an array (whitelist) of acceptable values. Otherwise, you introduce a code injection vulnerability (a severe one)

Comment: Yes. You can use call_user_func(); http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: You are advised to do something like `$allowed = array('do_this', 'do_that'); if (!in_array($_GET['func'], $allowed)) { // ERROR, don't execute! }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to call the function as you get the $_GET variables like this:

```
if(isset($_GET["func"])){
    $func = $_GET["func"];
    $func();

}
```

Comment: That isn't all that's needed. More protection is necessary to limit calls to acceptable functions.  For example `script.php?func=phpinfo` would dump server information to the screen.